# app restriction can’t be retrieved with the RestrictionsManager.getApplicationRestrictions in Android

Tags: android

I'm following the google documentation for how to get the application restriction:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/RestrictionsManager.html
https://developer.android.com/work/managed-configurations.html#define_restrictions

I've created a simple app in the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3W27jXj1LJyNmNtWUtJQ3BhcXc/view?usp=sharing

I debugged with samsung galaxy note4 with android OS version of 5.1.1 which is enrolled with Android for Work in google’s page. The current problems are:

1. app restriction can’t be retrieved with the RestrictionsManager.getApplicationRestrictions
2. “ACTION_APPLICATION_RESTRICTIONS_CHANGED” can’t be received.

Is there any problem in my code? Does anyone successfully get the application restrictions?

Comment: please add some code